# What means for i=a,1,-1 in pseudocode?

Tags: pseudocode

I have a code in pseudocode.

This is a line of code: `for i=k1,1,-1 do Ti <- Ti-1 + Ti`.

`k1` is an integer. `Ti` is an array.

The question is: what means `for i=k1,1,-1`? I know what is `for` but I don't know what is `i=k1,1,-1`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `i` assume values from `k1` to `1` with steps of `-1`. Equivalent to C:

```
for (i = k1; i >= 1; i += -1)
```

The syntax in your question is basically same as in Fortran, been around for decades:

```
      DO 10,i=k1,1,-1
      T(i) = T(i-1) + T(i)
10    CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the loop is counting downwards (-1) starting at k1, finishing at 1.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that `i` starts at `k1`  and decreases to `1` by steps of `-1` , i.e. in C

```
for (i=k1; i>=1; i--)
```